# Are there any rules for OOP?

Tags: oop, rules, solid-principles, package-design

Recently I heard that there are 9 rules for OOP(Java). I know only four as Abstraction, Polymorphism, Inheritance and Encapsulation. Are there any more rules for OOP?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Seems like what you're looking for are the [Principles of Object-Oriented Design](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod).

Summarized from [Agile Software Development Principles, Patterns, and Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135974445). These principles are the hard-won product of decades of experience in software engineering. They are not the product of a single mind, but they represent the integration and writings of a large number of software developers and researchers. Although they are presented here as principles of object-oriented design, they are really special cases of long-standing principles of software engineering.

**SRP The Single Responsibility Principle** A class should have only one reason to change.

**OCP The Open-Closed Principle** Software entities (classes, packages, methods, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification.

**LSP The Liskov Substition Principle** Subtypes must be substitutable for their base types.

**DIP The Dependency Inversion Principle** Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upons abstractions.

**ISP The Interface Segregation Principle**
Clients shold not be forced to depend upon methods that they do not use. Interfaces belong to clients, not to hierarchies.

**REP The Release-Reuse Equivalency Principle**
The granule of reuse is the granule of release.

**CCP The Common Closure Principle**
The classes in a package should be closed together against the same kinds of changes. A change that affects a closed package affects all the classes in that package and no other packages.

**CRP The Common Reuse Principle**
The classes in a package are reused together. If you reuse one of the classes in a package, you reuse them all.

**ADP The Acylcic Dependencies Principle**
Allow no cycles in the dependency graph.

**SDP The Stable Dependencies Principle**
Depend in the direction of stability.

**SAP The Stable Abstractions Principle**
A package should be as abstract as it is stable.

Comment: The first link hangs. Fortunately, there are other sources, i.e http://wiki.c2.com/?PrinciplesOfObjectOrientedDesign. This answer puts together principles of class design, principles of package cohesion, and principles of package coupling.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about any rules. All these mentioned things are more like OO paradigms to me. There are few advices we follow like,

- Separation of Concern
- Single Responsibility per Class
- Prefer Composition over Inheritance
- Programming to Interface
- Plus all mentioned by Billybob, already

Answer (score 5):

These OO principles are straight from [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124):

- Encapsulate what Varies
- Program to an Interface, rather than an Implementation
- Favour Composition over Inheritance
- A Class should have only one reason to Change (**Single Responsibility Principle**)
- Sub-Types must be substitutable for their Base (**Liskov Substitition Principle**)
- Classes shoule be Open for extension, but Closed for Modification (**Open-Closed Principle**)

Answer (score 4):

These are concepts, not rules. There are no rules really, just decisions to make, some designs are better than others, some much better than others :-)

There are plenty of guidelines though :-) Some are language specific (C++ is riddled with them) others are OO specific. Too many to list though :-)

Off the top of my head, important ones are:

- Loose coupling, high cohesion
- Write testable classes, which you test
- Use inheritence sparingly and only where it makes sense (prefer composition)
- Try stick to the open/close principle.
- (most important) KISS

Plenty to expand upon and add :-)

EDIT: I should add, the rules which you listed are not unique to OO

Comment: Neither yours :). By the way, how would we practice Inheritance, Polymorphism, etc. in a non-OO language. I believe all these 4 are OO paradigms.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Pragmatic Programmers - the rules are:

- Keep it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
- Keep it SHY (Ensure that your classes have high cohesion and low coupling)
- and tell the other GUY (Separation of concerns)

http://media.pragprog.com/articles/may_04_oo1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

There are no "Rules" to OOP.

There are 4 language properties that make a language object-oriented or not (these are the things you listed in your question).

The rest of the material out there are guidelines.  The best/most helpful guidelines I've read are [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28Object_Oriented_Design%29)

Many of the suggestions are not readily understandable by laymen (non-CS majors).  I thought GRASP was pragmatic and approachable.

I think GRASP is nice because it suggests the most critical part of OO in its name - Assignment of Responsibility (to objects not programmers).

The two most critical GRASP concepts from which everything else derives are coupling and cohesion.  These two concepts/principals drive all other patterns and approaches.

BTW - did I just interview you?  You transcribed the question incorrectly...